# Add R ggplot legend

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have been trying to add two legends to this plot:

[image: plot]

I want to add `geom_point(color = all_counts.dir_s2.results$genecolor)` as an additional legend.

```
plot_dir_s2 <-
  all_counts.dir_s2.results %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  ggplot(aes(log2(baseMean), log2FoldChange)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = pvalue < 0.05), cex = 0.1, position=position_jitter(w=0.01,h=0.1)) +
  geom_point(color = all_counts.dir_s2.results$genecolor) +
  labs(title = "RPS2 Torin Treated vs Untreated PNAS Genes", x = "log2Expression") +
  ylim(-4, 4)
  NULL
```

So I'm looking to make something like this:

[image: edited_plot]

Would I use `scale_color_manual` to manually add these in?

```
scale_color_manual(values = c("padj > 0.05" = "red",
                                "padj < 0.05" = "teal",
                                "PNAS genes" = "purple")
```

Data here:

```
all_counts.dir_s2.results <-
  structure(
    list(
      EnsGeneID = c(
        "ENSG00000109971",
        "ENSG00000285080",
        "ENSG00000105889",
        "ENSG00000008988",
        "ENSG00000156508",
        "ENSG00000167658",
        "ENSG00000106554",
        "ENSG00000109475",
        "ENSG00000111640",
        "ENSG00000258077",
        "ENSG00000005022",
        "ENSG00000026025",
        "ENSG00000163931",
        "ENSG00000220842",
        "ENSG00000070756",
        "ENSG00000065978",
        "ENSG00000228929",
        "ENSG00000180879",
        "ENSG00000226360",
        "ENSG00000244245",
        "ENSG00000232712",
        "ENSG00000204628",
        "ENSG00000186468",
        "ENSG00000233913",
        "ENSG00000229659",
        "ENSG00000219274",
        "ENSG00000149273",
        "ENSG00000147403",
        "ENSG00000137154",
        "ENSG00000203907",
        "ENSG00000198755",
        "ENSG00000213315",
        "ENSG00000228887",
        "ENSG00000197360",
        "ENSG00000221983",
        "ENSG00000234742",
        "ENSG00000178464",
        "ENSG00000240738",
        "ENSG00000224861",
        "ENSG00000228205",
        "ENSG00000166441",
        "ENSG00000123349",
        "ENSG00000212802",
        "ENSG00000187109",
        "ENSG00000218426",
        "ENSG00000129515",
        "ENSG00000235175",
        "ENSG00000110700",
        "ENSG00000230629",
        "ENSG00000166689",
        "ENSG00000133112",
        "ENSG00000232573",
        "ENSG00000227525",
        "ENSG00000145425",
        "ENSG00000065150",
        "ENSG00000122406",
        "ENSG00000239559",
        "ENSG00000242299",
        "ENSG00000170889",
        "ENSG00000105372",
        "ENSG00000184831",
        "ENSG00000096384",
        "ENSG00000139239",
        "ENSG00000198918",
        "ENSG00000220749",
        "ENSG00000225200",
        "ENSG00000237550",
        "ENSG00000196511",
        "ENSG00000226084",
        "ENSG00000075415",
        "ENSG00000213280",
        "ENSG00000214748",
        "ENSG00000137970",
        "ENSG00000051523",
        "ENSG00000236844",
        "ENSG00000228502",
        "ENSG00000104722",
        "ENSG00000174748",
        "ENSG00000178741",
        "ENSG00000225912",
        "ENSG00000220370",
        "ENSG00000185641",
        "ENSG00000227615",
        "ENSG00000198431",
        "ENSG00000237049",
        "ENSG00000146677",
        "ENSG00000243829",
        "ENSG00000224631",
        "ENSG00000260898",
        "ENSG00000243199",
        "ENSG00000114391",
        "ENSG00000232472",
        "ENSG00000232176",
        "ENSG00000142937",
        "ENSG00000181524",
        "ENSG00000236552",
        "ENSG00000235552",
        "ENSG00000125691",
        "ENSG00000223676",
        "ENSG00000241494"
      ),
      baseMean = c(
        1095.31857607063,
        592.445494739157,
        1177.80855319897,
        654.762885017899,
        541.069027423406,
        3385.31917292566,
        2346.6625765827,
        1900.17143907793,
        9214.50635932529,
        225.760894371447,
        582.702263829148,
        1269.66479230146,
        1022.67773974919,
        499.656500065798,
        2418.48464257135,
        998.530007694609,
        1074.9540137383,
        1720.49852346652,
        1052.38625395776,
        347.013381196818,
        152.145329613279,
        6509.31081914136,
        602.185990124399,
        591.274484606163,
        262.459320898851,
        152.253689386927,
        1803.54155562342,
        1687.54874792706,
        3414.814032345,
        668.569284831465,
        1321.53071412171,
        416.675934786263,
        506.203474547914,
        91.7960148395533,
        1564.81496127497,
        246.867404412426,
        184.648167904095,
        340.291172688643,
        193.73195681553,
        165.921885978623,
        845.238238207963,
        314.856420444992,
        684.508465885965,
        1175.59500763978,
        208.03565295281,
        423.619431032168,
        130.978685412339,
        698.054374521658,
        359.260523548016,
        292.541834401905,
        408.978425690628,
        1864.02534562533,
        224.041002260477,
        212.297994406831,
        338.551602588589,
        2634.40359801874,
        262.407724588084,
        828.081698719403,
        1365.56267740348,
        2302.46106349641,
        384.682787669164,
        9413.64738807171,
        812.173464451936,
        255.120920916547,
        97.5199433617571,
        782.971125416077,
        137.146562287411,
        92.5757279278087,
        157.667852340176,
        595.49169928228,
        387.222338554843,
        424.12061222847,
        475.366012597284,
        1017.48774062861,
        385.392011521195,
        189.366195768179,
        587.097225197315,
        1766.98793458201,
        743.836940934617,
        114.338914591437,
        112.882471243503,
        1308.8697110712,
        564.737601999289,
        858.32478049716,
        50.4799242404189,
        585.1960147226,
        358.486720273333,
        564.888713645347,
        21.4974919105639,
        843.804617919398,
        1020.3350422589,
        429.06380723344,
        265.954792068853,
        3059.5537229438,
        401.189242814625,
        1017.43141828211,
        2266.80553131293,
        2220.45893040228,
        52.877317604412,
        83.705572068192
      ),
      log2FoldChange = c(
        -2.0183653034074,-2.07101347509777,
        -2.20311149392739,
        -1.73134369022066,
        -1.86189372785931,-1.7222920979343,
        -1.58174836615284,
        -1.55463855546746,
        -1.58894875737464,-1.93714542684058,
        -1.61698688058756,
        -1.54229924438531,
        -1.35361317971803,-1.67070381160127,
        -1.2988292716825,
        -1.36536010862324,
        -1.40370428515576,-1.33795205375909,
        -1.31656369417928,
        -1.79401615862215,
        -1.9734309805019,-1.2758268423695,
        -1.40634659267066,
        -1.38656230355066,
        -1.63423748311413,-2.04669104755808,
        -1.31366149061346,
        -1.34310199306866,
        -1.10769678811283,-1.3049370056618,
        -1.11719488676431,
        -1.372098937987,
        -1.26266990702409,-2.16638812406429,
        -1.20935918804272,
        -1.48160015601683,
        -1.68353354818499,-1.31962005314326,
        -1.4756089749056,
        -1.6598052015808,
        -1.21719622822649,-1.30693509493117,
        -1.24169591343418,
        -1.02619910073139,
        -1.55236053768099,-1.21519830751149,
        -1.89677667206551,
        -1.21230124126626,
        -1.29326969250991,-1.26582179766441,
        -1.22216982890919,
        -1.09394036287155,
        -1.36715544338926,-1.45950706616776,
        -1.22329833446237,
        -0.990183714941196,
        -1.28110328655418,-1.11865028054913,
        -1.14329357304439,
        -1.14848611565117,
        -1.20155919925426,-0.941667790711213,
        -1.06145064849424,
        -1.27890379060449,
        -1.76318920759731,-1.02158388278365,
        -1.51780614286352,
        -1.87261391459523,
        -1.48882724039241,-1.05479533608263,
        -1.23283762446814,
        -1.16251688968316,
        -1.1283771329761,-1.03589083325477,
        -1.20517491245122,
        -2.73812031011786,
        -1.07921290542485,-1.11643907902893,
        -1.04249645226895,
        -1.74811951713493,
        -1.59950682107044,-1.0513227658533,
        -1.0209609392492,
        -0.956533826034593,
        -2.17345914920422,-1.00986691348105,
        -1.24042518500277,
        -1.01608286240974,
        -7.80331238832679,-0.920146611262127,
        -0.929016321108488,
        -1.09828795446757,
        -1.13165337360373,-0.859363504230098,
        -1.10306509825187,
        -0.977731739606374,
        -0.970556949127596,-0.960693084249075,
        -2.01832238081385,
        -1.71974919718578
      ),
      lfcSE = c(
        0.185690457540347,
        0.197587691894742,
        0.216823099095797,
        0.194030022145317,
        0.215109146062061,
        0.203267932075425,
        0.187353373767619,
        0.188746248799253,
        0.193024950572106,
        0.251990908283876,
        0.210635033935669,
        0.201533186952436,
        0.178205687341961,
        0.220020839056972,
        0.171916316053662,
        0.180816253942394,
        0.187364875633129,
        0.181676592919805,
        0.178986896136368,
        0.244230993901665,
        0.270657523604001,
        0.180178217975313,
        0.20308584941119,
        0.203884003544976,
        0.240421881913085,
        0.305001764731783,
        0.196598460818313,
        0.202902441606541,
        0.167968154466311,
        0.199955087856562,
        0.172373647324672,
        0.213421120095906,
        0.196705428238404,
        0.338577413899305,
        0.19002379912503,
        0.234112821836512,
        0.26849253899321,
        0.211876642968247,
        0.243373744853905,
        0.274827543674211,
        0.20338211880963,
        0.220050935322843,
        0.211864658778423,
        0.175179064564807,
        0.265727387177693,
        0.208547408214913,
        0.326598732786511,
        0.209563680243458,
        0.22435068632286,
        0.219650954906015,
        0.212405599884125,
        0.190624143132632,
        0.240565744719565,
        0.257548700955123,
        0.216182620743396,
        0.175446020027803,
        0.227540129469127,
        0.198860411804427,
        0.203389912890561,
        0.204625983303892,
        0.214565368435734,
        0.168616453895999,
        0.190265916943314,
        0.229741571933169,
        0.317043440592801,
        0.184172024726355,
        0.2748475074961,
        0.341578880584216,
        0.272005292742882,
        0.193836400874127,
        0.226612968926386,
        0.213773894092803,
        0.208134628711545,
        0.191089938186128,
        0.222856719094344,
        0.506387133649792,
        0.199845750874926,
        0.207910379556996,
        0.195531231586025,
        0.328423357098504,
        0.304765474434008,
        0.200699297461214,
        0.196835461555169,
        0.185438923940554,
        0.421507030882521,
        0.195952756297554,
        0.242418423385753,
        0.198723949961846,
        1.52764833135362,
        0.180139666958911,
        0.1822847025192,
        0.21567884104879,
        0.224327485817,
        0.170358717679317,
        0.219406249712663,
        0.194966274190596,
        0.19391390025223,
        0.194743296569751,
        0.409721457588268,
        0.349812088381184
      ),
      stat = c(
        -10.8695154836853,-10.4814902954635,
        -10.1608707887438,
        -8.92307113650685,
        -8.65557677088328,-8.47301431341972,
        -8.44259344971681,
        -8.23665935274265,
        -8.23183092478539,-7.68736237363899,
        -7.6767233369232,
        -7.65283012543889,
        -7.59579113275195,-7.59338896607274,
        -7.55500874784385,
        -7.55109166822042,
        -7.49182193520782,-7.36447129625382,
        -7.35564291352484,
        -7.34557121502962,
        -7.29124745628436,-7.08091608800518,
        -6.92488716839754,
        -6.8007410068578,
        -6.79737414128105,-6.71042362445978,
        -6.68195206180926,
        -6.61944717093717,
        -6.59468332930334,-6.52615054535596,
        -6.48123947078777,
        -6.42906820735649,
        -6.41909030336341,-6.39850159854015,
        -6.36425118122701,
        -6.32857331091192,
        -6.2703178065874,-6.22824693961679,
        -6.06313953787987,
        -6.03944269701142,
        -5.98477503996216,-5.93923899034433,
        -5.8607977403763,
        -5.85800080209783,
        -5.84192903173701,-5.82696432390666,
        -5.80766696760387,
        -5.78488237970379,
        -5.76450071852594,-5.76287864628693,
        -5.75394353809847,
        -5.73872933876173,
        -5.68308445154149,-5.66691682293545,
        -5.6586340301351,
        -5.64380836216335,
        -5.6302301028971,-5.62530405322348,
        -5.62119112396476,
        -5.61261134635839,
        -5.59996800981492,-5.58467319738573,
        -5.57877451488317,
        -5.56670601599486,
        -5.56134895678819,-5.54690042801847,
        -5.52235731257289,
        -5.48222978947769,
        -5.47352305309644,-5.44167829843059,
        -5.44027833141632,
        -5.4380676116537,
        -5.42138105495131,-5.42095959152896,
        -5.40784642863302,
        -5.40716801073286,
        -5.40022943044848,-5.36980924861844,
        -5.33161093403283,
        -5.32276246299564,
        -5.24832028313228,-5.2382981861532,
        -5.18687502334554,
        -5.15821492979127,
        -5.15640070025306,-5.15362443765564,
        -5.11687671125937,
        -5.1130367658494,
        -5.10805545240403,-5.10796220952272,
        -5.09651280809281,
        -5.0922378343971,
        -5.04464876197518,-5.04443515387198,
        -5.02750081046668,
        -5.01487625829358,
        -5.00509219744,-4.93312530480341,
        -4.92608415652488,
        -4.91620859972055
      ),
      pvalue = c(
        1.6105384639475e-27,
        1.05074740468397e-25,
        2.96417079172965e-24,
        4.53533247814602e-19,
        4.90425259485203e-18,
        2.39123187387306e-17,
        3.10373110219135e-17,
        1.77085766196957e-16,
        1.84373366907983e-16,
        1.50199274107305e-14,
        1.63209389674989e-14,
        1.96603559055405e-14,
        3.05917620449718e-14,
        3.11645243316854e-14,
        4.18831703432537e-14,
        4.31624897911202e-14,
        6.79240353188074e-14,
        1.77850315040926e-13,
        1.90010340573178e-13,
        2.04882205246095e-13,
        3.07098109300135e-13,
        1.43204600625457e-12,
        4.36323144701782e-12,
        1.04082390918688e-11,
        1.06543153285088e-11,
        1.94060198761294e-11,
        2.35780162668781e-11,
        3.60544662066692e-11,
        4.26164506980583e-11,
        6.74814962119917e-11,
        9.09721474995461e-11,
        1.28388512236458e-10,
        1.37091073947096e-10,
        1.56909101165909e-10,
        1.96244766091023e-10,
        2.47438291649186e-10,
        3.60311927938281e-10,
        4.71683204808732e-10,
        1.33489754819337e-09,
        1.546474198518e-09,
        2.16689139501711e-09,
        2.86348175138605e-09,
        4.60648782663971e-09,
        4.68472389599416e-09,
        5.15997893490219e-09,
        5.64446727370089e-09,
        6.33493652297021e-09,
        7.25630841901856e-09,
        8.18999292285693e-09,
        8.26912538076218e-09,
        8.71852861804007e-09,
        9.53895256422316e-09,
        1.3228690336629e-08,
        1.45389874839546e-08,
        1.52582531109057e-08,
        1.6632920782743e-08,
        1.79969358842075e-08,
        1.85181504215372e-08,
        1.89645323089349e-08,
        1.99295886015674e-08,
        2.14391365344425e-08,
        2.34140076079223e-08,
        2.4221898181661e-08,
        2.59599819464236e-08,
        2.676973112306e-08,
        2.9077822326956e-08,
        3.34481404929465e-08,
        4.19998201908752e-08,
        4.4117546051232e-08,
        5.27809286620383e-08,
        5.3197393894889e-08,
        5.38615366672493e-08,
        5.91403422530529e-08,
        5.92799600367521e-08,
        6.3787081174538e-08,
        6.40290759293059e-08,
        6.655572267256e-08,
        7.88199674497518e-08,
        9.73453251050117e-08,
        1.02203166303607e-07,
        1.53492275501923e-07,
        1.62064065367655e-07,
        2.13852137781182e-07,
        2.49315333058881e-07,
        2.51741885853566e-07,
        2.55499393055106e-07,
        3.10636522834479e-07,
        3.17020565839737e-07,
        3.25491137576376e-07,
        3.25651758940819e-07,
        3.45967166361943e-07,
        3.53861823338068e-07,
        4.54355220920421e-07,
        4.54863057911226e-07,
        4.96913387510328e-07,
        5.30676077367893e-07,
        5.5835300049354e-07,
        8.09242026518054e-07,
        8.38938764362226e-07,
        8.82363768510161e-07
      ),
      padj = c(
        1.38425780976288e-23,
        4.51558697162934e-22,
        8.49234931830545e-21,
        9.74529566241627e-16,
        8.43041021055063e-15,
        3.42543965932315e-14,
        3.81093840333353e-14,
        1.76076565397124e-13,
        1.76076565397124e-13,
        1.27525882205139e-11,
        1.27525882205139e-11,
        1.40817299173434e-11,
        1.91327919022026e-11,
        1.91327919022026e-11,
        2.31863499846674e-11,
        2.31863499846674e-11,
        3.43415931508911e-11,
        8.4923525432042e-11,
        8.59546777487613e-11,
        8.80481277045092e-11,
        1.25690869020698e-10,
        5.59474337443546e-10,
        1.56258226196326e-09,
        3.52207077878972e-09,
        3.52207077878972e-09,
        6.17758299390119e-09,
        7.23760892192204e-09,
        1.06857978291835e-08,
        1.22096131249937e-08,
        1.87097890303893e-08,
        2.44345502424562e-08,
        3.34393715961319e-08,
        3.46558170757439e-08,
        3.85323921291711e-08,
        4.68534379042317e-08,
        5.74792463979664e-08,
        8.14968689639349e-08,
        1.03951721675155e-07,
        2.8683611066805e-07,
        3.24193798445419e-07,
        4.43438846194573e-07,
        5.72363387282863e-07,
        8.94782264134885e-07,
        8.94782264134885e-07,
        9.64130846640964e-07,
        1.032216940797e-06,
        1.13434957114435e-06,
        1.27281573186662e-06,
        1.39359083622845e-06,
        1.39359083622845e-06,
        1.44107218215489e-06,
        1.5469301375377e-06,
        2.10556654524678e-06,
        2.27204722590164e-06,
        2.34186938371847e-06,
        2.50806937066098e-06,
        2.66695972284074e-06,
        2.69768648937478e-06,
        2.71666925325493e-06,
        2.80811170541757e-06,
        2.97208675021828e-06,
        3.19433960936654e-06,
        3.25292523236525e-06,
        3.43270838199247e-06,
        3.48614907579849e-06,
        3.73020720746548e-06,
        4.22774658142464e-06,
        5.23171673247206e-06,
        5.41700440443342e-06,
        6.34164257061655e-06,
        6.34164257061655e-06,
        6.34164257061655e-06,
        6.79348342021179e-06,
        6.79348342021179e-06,
        7.14714165730369e-06,
        7.14714165730369e-06,
        7.33392867141863e-06,
        8.5754129143116e-06,
        1.04585383659697e-05,
        1.08448915355494e-05,
        1.60886110724272e-05,
        1.6782417371506e-05,
        2.18816562408246e-05,
        2.51595524292023e-05,
        2.51595524292023e-05,
        2.52415779690648e-05,
        3.03400103836631e-05,
        3.06156377909274e-05,
        3.07579875614982e-05,
        3.07579875614982e-05,
        3.23216064660967e-05,
        3.27036814149537e-05,
        4.11531366604946e-05,
        4.11531366604946e-05,
        4.44892767255341e-05,
        4.70222771647117e-05,
        4.89698371351222e-05,
        7.02569213931583e-05,
        7.21067867969333e-05,
        7.50882830727212e-05
      ),
      mark = c(
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "ENSG00000008988",
        "ENSG00000156508",
        "ENSG00000167658",
        "",
        "ENSG00000109475",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "ENSG00000026025",
        "",
        "",
        "ENSG00000070756",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "ENSG00000186468",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "ENSG00000149273",
        "ENSG00000147403",
        "ENSG00000137154",
        "",
        "ENSG00000198755",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "ENSG00000166441",
        "",
        "",
        "ENSG00000187109",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "ENSG00000110700",
        "",
        "",
        "ENSG00000133112",
        "",
        "",
        "ENSG00000145425",
        "",
        "ENSG00000122406",
        "",
        "",
        "ENSG00000170889",
        "ENSG00000105372",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "ENSG00000198918",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "ENSG00000174748",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "ENSG00000114391",
        "",
        "",
        "ENSG00000142937",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "ENSG00000125691",
        "",
        ""
      ),
      gene = c(
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "RPS20",
        "EEF1A1",
        "EEF2",
        "",
        "RPL34",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "VIM",
        "",
        "",
        "PABPC1",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "RPS23",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "RPS3",
        "RPL10",
        "RPS6",
        "",
        "RPL10A",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "RPL27A",
        "",
        "",
        "NAP1L1",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "RPS13",
        "",
        "",
        "TPT1",
        "",
        "",
        "RPS3A",
        "",
        "RPL5",
        "",
        "",
        "RPS9",
        "RPS19",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "RPL39",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "RPL15",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "RPL24",
        "",
        "",
        "RPS8",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "RPL23",
        "",
        ""
      ),
      genecolor = c(
        NA,
        NA,
        NA,
        "red",
        "red",
        "red",
        NA,
        "red",
        NA,
        NA,
        NA,
        "red",
        NA,
        NA,
        "red",
        NA,
        NA,
        NA,
        NA,
        NA,
        NA,
        NA,
        "red",
        NA,
        NA,
        NA,
        "red",
        "red",
        "red",
        NA,
        "red",
        NA,
        NA,
        NA,
        NA,
        NA,
        NA,
        NA,
        NA,
        NA,
        "red",
        NA,
        NA,
        "red",
        NA,
        NA,
        NA,
        "red",
        NA,
        NA,
        "red",
        NA,
        NA,
        "red",
        NA,
        "red",
        NA,
        NA,
        "red",
        "red",
        NA,
        NA,
        NA,
        "red",
        NA,
        NA,
        NA,
        NA,
        NA,
        NA,
        NA,
        NA,
        NA,
        NA,
        NA,
        NA,
        NA,
        "red",
        NA,
        NA,
        NA,
        NA,
        NA,
        NA,
        NA,
        NA,
        NA,
        NA,
        NA,
        NA,
        "red",
        NA,
        NA,
        "red",
        NA,
        NA,
        NA,
        "red",
        NA,
        NA
      )
    ),
    row.names = c(NA, 100L),
    class = "data.frame"
  )
```

Comment: There are a couple ways to accomplish this. Can you post example data? If so, I can demonstrate. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, Skaqqs. I attached the dataframe to the link above (csv format). It's the same dataframe used to build this plot.

Comment: For security reasons, I can't use that site. Sorry! Can you post the results of `dput(all_counts.dir_s2.results)` as an edit to your question?

Comment: Completely understandable. I didn't know about dput, that's a cool tool. I posted the output above.

Comment: The plot might not look the same as it's only a small subset of the data frame. However, the method of changing colors should still hold true.

Comment: legends* not colors.

Comment: There are some missing levels in the data you shared. No problem, I can simulate some data, it is just a little harder for me to understand the structure of your data. Can a point be both PNAS and have a pvalue?

Comment: I just noticed your question was marked as a duplicate. Does the linked answer suit your question?

Comment: `df$gene <- ifelse(df$gene == "", "PNAS", df$gene); df$genecolor2 <- ifelse(df$gene == "PNAS", "PNAS genes", ifelse(df$pvalue > 0.0000001, "padj > 0.05", "padj < 0.05")); ggplot() + geom_point(data = df, aes(log2(baseMean), log2FoldChange, color = genecolor2)) + scale_color_manual("title", values = c("padj > 0.05" = "red", "padj < 0.05" = "blue3",  "PNAS genes" = "purple"))`

Comment: Above is the tidy way of doing it: make a new field in your data to define your symbology. Below is what the linked question suggests, which works.. but not as tidy: (in both cases I took liberties with defining your thresholds for pvalues for demonstration; also removed any non essential lines so it would fit in a comment)

Comment: `ggplot() + geom_point(data = df[df$gene == "PNAS",], aes(log2(baseMean), log2FoldChange, color = "PNAS genes")) + geom_point(data = df[df$gene != "PNAS" & df$pvalue > 0.0000001,], aes(log2(baseMean), log2FoldChange, color = "padj > 0.05")) + geom_point(data = df[df$gene != "PNAS" & df$pvalue <= 0.0000001,], aes(log2(baseMean), log2FoldChange, color = "padj < 0.05")) + scale_color_manual("title", values = c("padj > 0.05" = "red", "padj < 0.05" = "blue3",  "PNAS genes" = "purple"))`